# parameter for shell scripts that is started with qsub

Tags: linux, shell, grid-computing, qsub

how can I parametrize a shell script that is executed on a grid (started with qsub) ? I have a shell script, where I use getopts to read the parameters.

When I start (qsub script.sh -r firstparam -s secondparam ..) this working script with qsub I receive error messages,

> qsub: invalid option -- s
>
> qsub: illegal -r value

as qsub thinks the parameter are for itself. Yet I have not found any solution.

Thanks

Comment: I just figured out how to solve it:
just print the commands of the shell scrip with echo and pipe the result to qsub:


./script.sh | qsub

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer. Then come back and mark it accepted. By the way, did you try quoting the argument to `qsub`? `qsub 'script.sh -r firstparam -s secondparam'` I have no idea if that works in this case.

Comment: I've seen more than one command named `qsub`; are you referring to [this one](http://www.clusterresources.com/torquedocs/commands/qsub.shtml)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just figured out how to solve it: just print the commands of the shell scrip with echo and pipe the result to qsub:

`echo "./script.sh var1=13 var2=24" | qsub`

Comment: your answer needs to be more explicit - come up with an example

Comment: It seems my [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354186/using-a-loop-variable-in-a-bash-script-to-pass-different-command-line-args/11354348#11354348), is similar. How do I need to change my bash script? Can you give an example.

Comment: The problem in this answer is that the job name is always STDIN (as appears in qstat -a), at least for my case

Comment: @hammady just use `echo "./script.sh var1=13 var2=24" | qsub -N myjobname`

Comment: I'm afraid this just runs `script.sh` on the node where `qsub` is executed, not on the cluster.

Comment: In my qsub version (probably Univa Grid Engine, this is written in man, but no --version option exists) - there is nothing written about reading input. I'm afraid that's not portable and reliable. Anyway, glad that it works for you.

Answer (score 45):

Using the qsub -v option is the proper way:

```
qsub -v par_name=par_value[,par_name=par_value...] script.sh
```

par_name can be used as variable in the shell script.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! In my opinion the problem with this approach is the difference of the parameter handling for the use of one application as standalone or distributed app. Therefore I prefer the style described above.

Comment: What if I don't care about the names of variables (because in my script I use just $1, $2 and so on)? To be more precise, all I want is just to pass arguments to the script.

Comment: I also don't care about the names of the variables - I prefer the script to parse the options as it normally would when running directly from a terminal, even when run with qsub.

Answer (score 38):

In addition to volk's answer, in order to reference the variables in the list (designated by -v) you simply use the name you define in your call. So, say you made a call to qsub as follows

`qsub -v foo='qux' myRunScript.sh`

Then `myRunScript.sh` could look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=16,walltime=0:00:59
#PBS -l mem=62000mb
#PBS -m abe

bar=${foo}
echo "${bar}"
```

Where the output would be

```
qux
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @_jhrf I think you wanted `$bar`

Comment: You're right. I've looked at this answer many times and not seen that error! Thanks.

Comment: @Manolete and @jhrf because you specifically gave `bash`, it does not matter in this case.  Though the ` = ` (with spaces **is** a syntax problem...).  See [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18136920/3814202) for why `$bar` and `${bar}` both work here :)

Answer (score 20):

## There is a better way...

I'm really surprised at how long this question has gone without a good answer. It may be that the specific version of `qsub` wasn't specified. `qsub` exists in at least Torque and also Sun Grid Engine, maybe other schedulers. So, it's important to know which you're using. I'll talk about a few here:

## TORQUE: `qsub -F <arguments> command`

[man page](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-0-2/Content/topics/commands/qsub.htm)
Here's an example of how I normally use it. Starting with this example script which just echoes any arguments passed to it:

```
$ cat testArgs.pbs
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $@
```

I would submit the job like this:

```
$ qsub -F "--here are the --args" testArgs.pbs
3883919.pnap-mgt1.cm.cluster
```

And this is what the output file looks like after it runs:

```
$ cat testArgs.pbs.o3883919
--here are the --args
```

## Sun Grid Engine: `qsub command [ command_args ]`

[man page](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qsub.html)
You just add the arguments after the command, same as you would when executing in the shell. I don't have SGE running anywhere, so no example for this one. But it's the same with Slurm, which is below

## Slurm: `sbatch command [ command_args ]`

[man page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html)
Here I submit the same script I used with the Torque example above:

```
$ sbatch testArgs.sh what the heck
Submitted batch job 104331
```

And the results:

```
$ cat slurm-104331.out
what the heck
```

## Exporting environment variables != passing arguments

Exporting environment variables is very different from passing arguments to a command.
[Here is a good discussion on the differences.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443366/argument-passing-strategy-environment-variables-vs-command-line)

The `qsub` answers above all recommend `-v`. To be clear, `-v` exports environment variables, `-F` passes arguments to the command.

I generally prefer to parameterize my scripts by allowing for arguments. In fact, I would say it's much more common to use scripts like this `process_data.sh --threads 8` than doing something like `export THREADS=8; process_data.sh`.

Comment: Thanks! In my environment, man qsub says there is no -F option, but I tried anyway and it works! Probably this option was added recently. But it is the right answer to this question.

Comment: thanks! I am using qsub (Sun Grid Engine) and it works! note that you don't need to add "command" as a key word. ```qsub script.sge arguments```