# bash script PBS_ARRAYID variable argument does not qsub to job

Tags: bash, argv, hpc, qsub

I want to pass the PBS_ARRAYID to the main argument vector (argv) through qsub but after reading every return in pages of google results - I cannot get this to work. A constant argument qsubs fine.

```
#
#$ -cwd
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -j y
#$ -t 1-3
#$ -pe fah 1
var1=$(echo "$PBS_ARRAYID" -l)
const1=1
./daedalus_linux_1.3_64 $const1 $var1
```

I lifted the Array code from the solution given here [Using a loop variable in a bash script to pass different command-line args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354186/using-a-loop-variable-in-a-bash-script-to-pass-different-command-line-args?lq=1)

From everything I have read this should work. And it does work with the exception of `var1=$(echo "$PBS_ARRAYID" -l)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer is fairly simple, our University uses a Sun Grid Engine queue - SGE

The tutorials I found by search were all  by chance for PBS queue

```
#
#$ -cwd
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -j y
#$ -t 1-9
#$ -pe fah 3
const1=1
./daedalus_linux_1.3_64 $const1 $SGE_TASK_ID
```