# Sun Grid Engine: How do I pass an argument into a job script?

Tags: sungridengine

I am using the Sun Grid Engine (SGE) to submit embarassingly parallel task arrays. Suppose I have the file `job_script`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -cwd -V
#$ -l h_rt=0:01:00
#$ -o logs
#$ -e logs
#$ -N name_of_code
#$ -t 1-1000

count=1
echo "hello $count" > output.${count}
./cpp_code $count
```

which can be submitted using `qsub job_script`. **What I am stuck on:** writing a for loop whereby the variable `count` is passed into `job_script` as an argument. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -cwd -V
#$ -l h_rt=0:01:00
#$ -o logs
#$ -e logs
#$ -N name_of_code
#$ -t 1-1000

count=$1
echo "hello $count" > output.${count}
./cpp_code $count
```

I (incorrectly) thought that `count` corresponds to the first argument passed from the command line into `job_script`, but

```
for count in {1..10..1}
do
  qsub job_script $count
done
```

does not work. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it? Thank you for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [parameter for shell scripts that is started with qsub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504081/parameter-for-shell-scripts-that-is-started-with-qsub)

Comment: Thanks vince that's perfect

Comment: So was it the issue? Because your example should work.